# How to create a Widget.Holo.Spinner-style widget in v7

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a `Button` that I want to style like a Holo-style spinner, i.e. underlined with a triangle in the bottom right corner - the built-in contacts app for example does that.

[image]

The easiest way is to create the button and style it as `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner"` - that gives me the visual result I want.

However, my app is meant to support Android 2.x, so I can't use native Holo styles. AppCompat has several spinner-related styles, like `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner` and others, but they don't look the same - they just create a little triangle in the center at the right edge of the widget, and no underline.

I could fudge it by creating my own 9-patch background, but I can't imagine that this Holo spinner style is missing from v7's AppCompat. Is there a style I can use, or any other way to create the visual result I want without creating my own drawable resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User "ozi" got me there, unfortunately his answer got deleted because it was just a link.

The trick is to use a custom attribute and override it with a v11-specific section. Here's the basic setup if you use themes:

In values/attr.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyApp">
    <attr name="holoSpinnerStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

You create your Spinner-Button like this:

```
<Button
    style="?attr/holoSpinnerStyle"
     />
```

And here's the key: You have different values in the theme depending on whether or not you have v11:

In values/themes.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="holoSpinnerStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner</item>
</style>
```

In values-v11/themes.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="holoSpinnerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner</item>
</style>
```

If you don't use themes, your setup is almost identical - you just use styles.xml, create a specific style for your button, and use that.

In pre-v11, this will create an old-style spinner, but that's actually good - a v11 spinner would look out of place in pre-v11 environment.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend you to style a button like a spinner. Android have created a particular style for the [button](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html) for a reason. THe reason behind this simple; you are going to confuse the users of your app if you style a button like a spinner, and they will think that the button is a spinner. That is why the Android design team do not recommend this.

Nonetheless, if you still wish to show the button as a sninner, you can always copy the design of the spinner, save it as an image and set it as the background of yuor button through this xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/spinner"
```

The spinner drawable needs to be saved in the drawables folder as an image.

Comment: Like I said, the built-in contacts app does it. I checked out their UI, it's really a Button that looks like a spinner. I'm intending to bring up a popup window when you click on it (again, like the contacts app), so the behavior isn't that unexpected.

Comment: then you can just create a drawable from this image for example http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZGFW.png and create the image from there. Alternatively you could use this site: http://android-holo-colors.com/ I found it awesome personally

Comment: @EboMike can you please accept and upvote the answer if this has helped you? I would more than eager to help you otherwise

Comment: Sorry, been away - my question was specifically about styling the widget without using a drawable (although I have to say your android-holo-colors link is awesome,and that alone is worth an upvote).

Comment: hmmmm, it's difficult to create it without using drawables. Although I've heard about 9 patch which could help you. never used it though