# Android Toolbar - How to implement Spinner for navigation mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

What is *currently* the correct way to implement the View Control (**No. 2**  from the below screenshot taken from [Android's design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)):
[image: Action Bar design]

I found [this example](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/07/android-actionbar-drop-down-navigation.html) but when I tried to replicate it, I noticed that methods like: 
**actionBar.setNavigationMode()** are already deprecated.

So how should I implement it? I thought at first that [it's a Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658287/replace-the-action-bars-title-with-a-spinner-drop-down) but I see apparently that it's not exactly the same 
and can I still use ActionBar or should I better move to use [Toolbar](http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/) (yes, I am confused...)

Comment: You mean that this design is not the recommended one by google anymore, altough it appear in the tutotial?

Comment: A lot appear in the tutorial, that is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly said, the `setNavigationMode()` method is now considered *passé*. To get the spinner in API 21, you need to use the `Toolbar` in this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Add the above code to your `Activity`'s layout. To set up the `Toolbar` in this `Activity`, you need to do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: And this code should be part of the layout.xml of the relevant activity?

Comment: The UI element that in my question's screen shot is not exactly Spinner - in spinner the arrow is in the middle of the text whereas in the view control it's opened by a triangle at the bottom-right corner. How do I create this element, in case it's not deprecated anymore...

Comment: OK, and is Spinner shoud be the most recommended way to display different views in Activity, instead of View Control?

Comment: What are you referring to as `View Control` ? There is no such widget in the Android framework. What you have shown in your question is a spinner ...

Comment: And to answer your question as to "what is most recommended way", the answer is always that **IT DEPENDS**

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I changed the style of the activity to 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar' otherwise I got an exception (Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead). In addition, I got confused because the Spinner's style in 'AppCompat' theme doesn't look like in the screenshot above, that is probably using 'Holo' Theme. Apparently it's not recommended to change the look of the spinner's button in different themes. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924627/how-to-create-a-widget-holo-spinner-style-widget-in-v7)