# How to make my spinner looks like this one?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm working on a spinner, and I saw this pic from developer.android.com.

[image: Spinner Appearance]

This kind of effect is exactly (The way "Home" shows) what I want, but I don't know how to make Spinner looks like it. Android's default effect makes the spinner looks like a bar which is ugly. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: try to put style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner" in the spinner declaration in xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27080718/2308683

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924627/how-to-create-a-widget-holo-spinner-style-widget-in-v7

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/osversions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selVersion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/osversions"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner spinnerOsversions;
    TextView selVersion;
    private String[] state = { "Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
       "Gingerbread", "HoneyComb", "IceCream Sandwich", "Jellybean",
       "kitkat" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println(state.length);
        selVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selVersion);
        spinnerOsversions = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.osversions);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);
        adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerOsversions.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        spinnerOsversions.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spinnerOsversions.setSelection(position);
        String selState = (String) spinnerOsversions.getSelectedItem();
        selVersion.setText("Selected Android OS:" + selState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```